# What is a [[ param1, param2 ... ]] structure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, handsontable

I'm working with handsontable, but am not knowledgeable about JavaScript. I have:

```
$container.handsontable({
              startRows: 8,
              startCols: 6,
              rowHeaders: true,
              colHeaders: true,
              minSpareRows: 1,
              contextMenu: true,
              afterChange: function (change, source) {
                if (source === 'loadData') {
                  console.log(change);
                }
```

When I look in the console I see:

```
  [[4, "notes", "PLEASE SET", ""]]
```

This does not look like a standard object. what is it and how can I access its parameters?

Comment: i guess thats's array of array sent as parameter to afterChange function.. !

Comment: its multidimensional array containing list of changes at first level and at second it give you `row`, `prop`, `oldVal`, `newVal` - read [documentation](https://github.com/handsontable/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Events#events-available-in-011)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an [array](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays) where the first element is an array containing 4 elements.

#### Try this in your browser JavaScript console (press F12, then go to console) or in [jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com/?var%20arr%20%3D%20%20[[4%2C%20%22notes%22%2C%20%22PLEASE%20SET%22%2C%20%22%22]]%3B%20%2F%2F%20Initialize%20the%20array%0A%0Aconsole.log%20%28arr[0]%29%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20[4%2C%20%22notes%22%2C%20%22PLEASE%20SET%22%2C%20%22%22]%0Aconsole.log%20%28arr[0][0]%29%3B%20%2F%2F%204%0Aconsole.log%20%28arr[0][1]%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22notes%22%0Aconsole.log%20%28arr[0][2]%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22PLEASE%20SET%22%0Aconsole.log%20%28arr[0][3]%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22%22%0Aconsole.log%20%28arr[1]%29%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20undefined%0Aconsole.log%20%28arr[2]%29%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20undefined):

```js
var arr =  [[4, "notes", "PLEASE SET", ""]]; // Initialize the array

console.log (arr[0]);    // [4, "notes", "PLEASE SET", ""]
console.log (arr[0][0]); // 4
console.log (arr[0][1]); // "notes"
console.log (arr[0][2]); // "PLEASE SET"
console.log (arr[0][3]); // ""
console.log (arr[0][4]); // undefined
console.log (arr[1]);    // undefined
console.log (arr[1][0]); // undefined
```